# How do I recursively remove subdirectories and files, but not the first parent directory?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal

I'm able to use the following to remove the target directory and recursively all of its subdirectories and contents.

```
find '/target/directory/' -type d -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

However, I do not want the target directory to be removed.  How can I remove just the files in the target, the subdirectories, and their contents?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The previous answer is almost correct. However, you shouldn't quote the [shell glob characters](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) if you want them to work. So, this is the command you're looking for:

```
rm -rf "/target/directory with spaces/"*
```

Note that the * is outside of the double quotes. This form would also work:

```
rm -rf /target/directory\ with\ spaces/*
```

If you have the `*` in quotes as shown above, then it will only attempt to remove the single file literally named `*` inside the target directory.

Comment: This does not work with hidden files and folders. I had to do it once more with a

Answer (score 8):

Three more options.

1. Use `find` with `-mindepth 1` and `-delete`:

   > −mindepth levels 
   >   Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels (a non‐negative integer).
   >   −mindepth 1 means process all files except the command line arguments.
   >
   > -delete  
   >   Delete  files;  true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed, an error message is issued.
   >   If −delete fails, find’s exit status will be nonzero  (when  it  eventually  exits).   Use  of
   >   −delete automatically turns on the −depth option.
   >   **Test carefully with the -depth option before using this option.**

   ```
   # optimal?
   # -xdev      don't follow links to other filesystems
   find '/target/dir with spaces/' -xdev -mindepth 1 -delete

   # Sergey's version
   # -xdev      don't follow links to other filesystems
   # -depth    process depth-first not breadth-first
   find '/target/dir with spaces/' -xdev -depth -mindepth1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
   ```

2.  Use `find`, but with files, not directories.  This avoids the need to `rm -rf`:

```
    # delete all the files;
    find '/target/dir with spaces/' -type f -exec rm {} \;

    # then get all the dirs but parent
    find '/target/dir with spaces/' -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} \;

    # near-equivalent, slightly easier for new users to remember
    find '/target/dir with spaces/' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
    find '/target/dir with spaces/' -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir
```

3. Go ahead and remove the parent directory, but recreate it.  You could create a bash function to do this with one command; here's a simple one-liner:

```
    rm -rf '/target/dir with spaces' ; mkdir '/target/dir with spaces'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
rm -rf /target/directory\ path/*
```

If there may be files starting with . in the target directory.

```
rm -rf "/target/directory path/*" "/target/directory path/.??*"
```

This second will match everything starting with a ., except . and ..
It will fail on names like .a, but that isn't very common.  It could be tweaked if necessary to cover all of the cases.

Comment: I tried both and they don't work for me.  Perhaps it is because my target directory path has spaces in it?  
rm -rf '/target/directory path/*'
It gives no error, but the subdirectories remain.

Comment: You need to escape the spaces, either with a backslash (\\) before the space, or by enclosing the entire directory name in quotes ("). I edited the examples to show this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that to as shown in my previous comment and still no go.  (I'm using OS X, does that matter?)

Comment: OS X should work fine, that is what I'm using.  Make sure that you don't both use backslash and quotes. Only one or the other.

Comment: Yes, just using the quotes.  If I remove the * and so I'm only using rm -rf "/target/directory path/" the "directory path" directory will be removed along with "directory path" subdirectories.  If I use the rm -rf "/target/directory path/*", nothing happens.

Comment: I suppose I could accomplish what I want in two steps, recursively delete the "/target/directory path" then create a new "/target/directory path".  That just seems weird.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /target/directory/ -xdev -depth -mindepth 1 -exec rm -Rf {} \;
```